# Multiple Windows Desktop areas for Full-Screen applications

Tags: windows, window-manager, fullscreen

Is it possible to run multiple instances of Windows Explorer within a single user session, or configure multiple desktops that are portions of a screen?

I don't know the best way to describe what I want to achieve, but here's a picture of what I've got:[image: Desktop Layout]

I've got a 4 monitor setup, 3 portrait and one landscape, and I am normally running a number of RDP sessions, outlook, chrome, a development environment or two, so on and so forth.  Most of these applications support full-screen views which mostly or completely hide the window borders, but on the Windows Desktop they take up a full monitor to do so.

What I want to do is have 7 "desktops", "regions", call them what you will, each of which is, for the purposes of applications running in it, a "full screen" environment:[image]

I'm not tied to Windows Explorer for this, in case it helps - a different window manager that will support this functionality would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: I never did, no.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) can create multiple virtual desktops, and should be able to set one to each monitor. I am unsure about setting two to each of the three portrait monitors though.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that VirtuaWin is free and open source.

Comment: I didn't see any way to set a desktop on each monitor either in the FAQ or in the application's setup pages.